# trying to convert html to a rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I am trying to convert the following html into a ruby helper:

```
<a href="home.html" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
    <i class="flaticon-insignia"></i>
    <span>home</span>
</a>
```

Here is my code so far that does not work:

```
link_to home_path(media), class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' do
  content_tag(:i, class: 'flaticon-insignia') {}
  content_tag(:span) do 
      menu_item.title
  end
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
<a class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom" href="/">
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: When you say it "does not work," what symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: @Philip7899, when your block has more than one `content_tag`, you need to `concat` them, add `concat` to each `content_tag` you have in your block. This is an example: `concat(content_tag...)`

Comment: Why do you want to use helper and not partial?

Comment: @Tass I edited my question to show the output of the Ruby helper.  It is only printing the span to the screen but not the i tag.

Comment: @MuradYusufov I need to use a helper based on my current architecture

Comment: @fanta I am getting the error undefined method concat

Answer (score 1):

`link_to`, when passed a block, will wrap `<a>` tags around whatever the block *returns*. In your code:

```
link_to home_path(media), class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' do
  content_tag(:i, class: 'flaticon-insignia') {}
  content_tag(:span) do 
      menu_item.title
  end
end
```

the only thing being *returned* is the final method call (`content_tag(:span) do ... end`). There are multiple ways of writing this, such as using `String#concat`, but here's how I normally do it:

```
link_to home_path(media), class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' do
  link_text = content_tag(:i, class: 'flaticon-insignia') {}
  link_text << content_tag(:span) do 
      menu_item.title
  end
end
```

Note also that in your example, `menu_item.title` is `Home` not `home`; and `home_path(media)` is `/` not `home.html` - so you still won't end up with identical HTML. However, those are both separate issues for you to think about.

Comment: I'm pretty sure one needs `.html_safe` somewhere there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, we're attempting to assist the person asking the question, not nit-picking every character in the code we're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the **content_tags** together, using the `+ symbol`:

```
link_to home_path(media), class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' do
  content_tag(:i, '', class: 'flaticon-insignia') + content_tag(:span, menu_item.title)
end
```

That should do it